# как совершить действие над динамически изменяющеемся контентом

Tags: javascript, jquery

столкнулся с проблемой, что скрипты не срабатывают над изображениями которые грузяться отдельно от страницы

```
html:
<div class="lott-item"><img src="" class="img-bg</div>
```

js:

```
$(".lottery .lott-item").each(function() {
        var imgSrc = $(this).find(".img-bg").attr("src");
        $(this).parent().css("background", "url(" + imgSrc + ") no-repeat center center");
        $(this).parent().css("backgroundSize", "cover");
        $(this).css("display", "none"); 
    });

    $(".lottery .lott-item").hover(function() {
        var imgSrc = $(this).find(".img-bg").attr("src");
        $(this).css("background", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, .4), rgba(0,0,0, .4)), url(" + imgSrc + ") no-repeat center center");
        $(this).css("backgroundSize", "cover");
    }, function() {
        var imgSrc = $(this).find(".img-bg").attr("src");
        $(this).css("background", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 0), rgba(0,0,0, 0)), url(" + imgSrc + ") no-repeat center center");
        $(this).css("backgroundSize", "cover");
    });
```

Comment: используйте `onload`

Comment: я использую $(function() {}); ну и во внутирь это все вставляю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ждем пока все загрузится, только потом бежим....

```
$(document).on("load", function(){
$(".lottery .lott-item").each(function() {
        var imgSrc = $(this).find(".img-bg").attr("src");
        $(this).parent().css("background", "url(" + imgSrc + ") no-repeat center center");
        $(this).parent().css("backgroundSize", "cover");
        $(this).css("display", "none"); 
    });

    $(".lottery .lott-item").hover(function() {
        var imgSrc = $(this).find(".img-bg").attr("src");
        $(this).css("background", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, .4), rgba(0,0,0, .4)), url(" + imgSrc + ") no-repeat center center");
        $(this).css("backgroundSize", "cover");
    }, function() {
        var imgSrc = $(this).find(".img-bg").attr("src");
        $(this).css("background", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0, 0), rgba(0,0,0, 0)), url(" + imgSrc + ") no-repeat center center");
        $(this).css("backgroundSize", "cover");
    });
})
```